# Using cleveref with tagged equations

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

In my document I have a tagged equation, something that goes like

```
\begin{equation}\tag{$\dagger$}\label{whatever}  \end{equation}
```

Then latter I want to refer to it using `\eqref{whatever}`. But instead of a desired output (`$\dagger$`) I get something like `(3)`. How do I fix this? (I also use `hyperref` and `amsrefs` in addition to `cleveref`.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Please keep in mind that it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Even though it may be trivial, any time you can save of those trying to help is appreciated.

Comment: when I compile your code snippet, and change `dagger` to `\dagger` everything works as (I think) expected. you mention `cleveref` in your title, but your code snippet doesn't use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there's a load order preference when dealing with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), answered in [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764) `cleveref` should be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Since the only information at hand indicates the use of `hyperref`, `cleveref` and [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (due to `\tag`), the following load order works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{cleveref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref
\begin{document}
See~\eqref{whatever} \ldots 
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \tag{$\dagger$}\label{whatever}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For me your code compiles to "See (1)..." (i.e., same problem as with my code). I'm using TeXShop under MacOS X.

Comment: @LaTeXdominator: Then could have an outdated distribution or outdated packages. Add `\listfiles` *before* `\documentclass` and post the contents *after* `**File List**` in your `.log` file via [an edit to your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/44483/edit).

Comment: I've updated my system and it works now. Thanks!